# Some workers are not loaded in sidekiq job, giving NameError:uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sidekiq-cron

I am scheduling some background jobs using sidekiq-cron. I am using config/schedule.yml file:

```
development:
  daily_summary:
    cron: "0 4 * * *"
    class: "DailySummaryWorker"
  weekly_summary:
    cron: "0 3 * * 1"
    class: "WeeklySummaryWorker"
  screenshot:
    cron: "0 5 * * *"
    class: "HomeScreenshotWorker"
staging:
  daily_summary:
    cron: "0 4 * * *"
    class: "DailySummaryWorker"
  weekly_summary:
    cron: "0 3 * * 1"
    class: "WeeklySummaryWorker"
  screenshot:
    cron: "0 5 * * *"
    class: "HomeScreenshotWorker"
  ground_close:
    cron: '30 * * * *'
    class: 'FedexGroundCloseWorker'
production:
  daily_summary:
    cron: "0 4 * * *"
    class: "DailySummaryWorker"
  weekly_summary:
    cron: "0 3 * * 1"
    class: "WeeklySummaryWorker"
  screenshot:
    cron: "0 5 * * *"
    class: "HomeScreenshotWorker"
  cleanup:
    cron: "30 0 * * *"
    class: "LabelCleanupWorker"
  ground_close:
    cron: '30 * * * *'
    class: 'FedexGroundCloseWorker'
```

and loading the jobs from config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
...
schedule_file = "#{Rails.root}/config/schedule.yml"
Rails.logger.info schedule_file
if File.exist?(schedule_file) 
  Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash(YAML.load_file(schedule_file)[Rails.env])
end
...
```

All job are working fine, except the newly added job i.e ground_close. It is giving the following error:

```
2023-01-22T08:30:13.564Z 14738 TID-1arc50 WARN: {"retry":3,"queue":"default","class":"FedexGroundCloseWorker","args":[],"jid":"9eaf340c42b913963e3a0b9e","created_at":1674376213.5620716,"enqueued_at":1674376213.5621684}
2023-01-22T08:30:13.564Z 14738 TID-1arc50 WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant FedexGroundCloseWorker
2023-01-22T08:30:13.564Z 14738 TID-1arc50 WARN: /var/www/[filtered]/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
/var/www/[filtered]/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
/var/www/[filtered]/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
/var/www/[filtered]/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
/var/www/[filtered]/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
/var/www/[filtered]/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/var/www/[filtered]/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:124:in `process'
/var/www/[filtered]/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:80:in `process_one'
/var/www/[filtered]/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:68:in `run'
/var/www/[filtered]/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:17:in `watchdog'
/var/www/[filtered]/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
2023-01-22T08:30:13.564Z 22552 TID-1igvv8 INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: ground_close
```

Or, sometime starts the job but nothing happens

```
2023-01-23T13:20:19.661Z 53394 TID-12czxw FedexGroundCloseWorker JID-2f008194caf73a92b1a31641 INFO: start
2023-01-23T13:20:19.673Z 53394 TID-1iin2s INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: ground_close
2023-01-23T13:20:20.225Z 53394 TID-12czxw FedexGroundCloseWorker JID-2f008194caf73a92b1a31641 INFO: done: 0.564 sec
```

The job is working fine in staging server. It is not working in production only.

For version information:

- Ruby: 2.1.2
- Rails: 4.1.1
- sidekiq: 4.1.2
- sidekiq-cron: 0.4.3

Comment: What have you tried to fix the problem? Have you made sure that the FedexGroundCloseWorker code is on the production server and is being autoloaded? You may also want to remove the name of your website from the logs.

Comment: @ramblex I think the FedexGroundCloseWorker is loaded because I can access it in console. Is there any other way of knowing if a class is loaded or not?

Answer (score 0):

It seem like sidekiq-cron require worker classes to be eager loaded. so add following line in config/application.rb

```
config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/workers/*"]
```

make absolutely sure that sidekiq is restarted.

check this thread for more information:  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13142#issuecomment-275492070